# My VPC is greyed out when trying to create a EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, aws-vpc

I am trying to create an instance into my already created VPC network. For some reason when I am in the middle of the launch, I cannot select my VPC and it only lets me select a default VPC which is not what I want.

[image: VPC greyed out]

Comment: is the region of your vpc and the region you are creating ec2 into are same ?

Comment: Try to launch the same AMI into that VPC  using awscli and see what error message you get.

Comment: @jarmod I get "An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
i-0787e4282810ef9cf"

Comment: @varnit Yes they are the same

Comment: Does your VPC have any subnets in it?

Comment: Is there anything special about the AMI you're launching? Is it a standard, AWS-provided AMI?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes it does have subnets, private and public.

Comment: @jarmod No everything is just standard. All I am simply trying to do is create a normal EC2 instance into my already created VPC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for grey-out is because the VPC is created with "dedicated" tenancy. Changing the VPC to"default" tenancy will solve the issue. Apparently, there is no option to make that change in the AWS GUI. Either you have to delete and re-create the VPC with default tenancy or modify the tenancy value using the AWS CLI.

To modify the instance tenancy attribute of a VPC using the AWS CLI

Use the modify-vpc-tenancy command to specify the ID of the VPC and instance tenancy value. The only supported value is default.

aws ec2 modify-vpc-tenancy --vpc-id vpc-1a2b3c4d --instance-tenancy default

Answer (score 4):

Alright so the solution was that the AMI was not compatible with my Dedicated Tenancy on my VPC so I had to delete and redo the entire VPC as default instead of Dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably does not have any Subnet private or public in your VPC can you please confirm?

Comment: if this is the case there are two probabilities , please try to check if this work for a different instance size for Example if you're using t2.micro change it to t2.small or something else please make sure that VPC is launched in the same reason where you were launching your instance .

Answer (score 0):

I want to also point out that the AZ may not have any instances of that TYPE available. This will cause the VPC to be greyed out as well. I was trying to create a t2.medium or below in us-east-1c and I was seeing my VPC greyed out until I changed to an M or T3 type.